# Expresión regular para filtrar ciertos caracteres que no debería admitir @

Tags: javascript, regex

¿Por qué esta expresión regular permite pasar caracteres como @ o \ aunque no estén en la lista de caracteres aceptables?

> var patron=/[^A-ZÑÁËÍÓÚÜa-zñáéíóúü0-9;.-_*$%"&!()¿?{}/]/;

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ejemplo de JavaScript</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<script>

var contrasena=prompt('Ingrese una password:');

 if (password_valida(contrasena))
   alert("Password OK");
  else
   alert("Password KO");


function password_valida(texto){
  
  /* 1. Comprobar si tiene al menos una Mayuscula */
  /* 2. Comprobar si tiene al menos una minuscula */
  /* 3. Comprobar si tiene al menos un número */
  /* 4. Comprobar la longitud */
  /* 5. Permitir solo la entrada de algunos caracteres especiales */
  
   puntos=0;
  
 //Tiene minúsculas incluidas acentuadas
    var patron=/[a-zñáéíóúü]/;
    if (patron.test(texto))
 {
    console.log('tiene minuscula');
  puntos++;
 }
 
 //Tiene mayusculas incluidas acentuadas
 var patron=/[A-ZÑÁËÍÓÚÜ]/;
 if (patron.test(texto))
 {
  console.log('tiene mayuscula');
  puntos++;
 }
 
 //Tiene un número
 var patron=/[0-9]/;
 if (patron.test(texto))
 {
  console.log('tiene numero');
  puntos++;
 }
 
 // Tiene una longigitud entre 8 y 16
 if ( texto.length >=8 && texto.length <=16 )
 {
  console.log('Longitud correcta');
  puntos++;
 }
 
 // No admite otros signos que no sean estos
  var patron=/[^A-ZÑÁËÍÓÚÜa-zñáéíóúü0-9;.-_*$%"&!()¿?{}/]/;
  if ( patron.test(texto) )
 {
  console.log('Caracter no valido');
  puntos--;
 }
 
 console.log(texto);
 console.log(puntos);
 
 if ( puntos==4 ) 
  return true;
 else
  return false;
 
  };
</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vi que algunos de los validadores que muestras sólo aplican al primer caracter del texto a validar. Te sugiero revisar [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp] contiene una explicación muy completa del tema. Y, es de lectura rápida

Answer (score 2):

Hay un par de cosas a corregir.

Primero, en lugar de buscar caracteres inválidos, comprueba que **todos** los caracteres que tienes son válidos. Si no se cumple significa que hay alguno no válido.

Además, has de tener cuidado al utilizar el `-` dentro de `[]`. Como bien sabrás, el guión sirve para especificar rangos (como `a-z`). Así que si lo dejas en medio estarás utilizando un rango. En tu caso tenías un rango entre `.-_` lo cual hacía que fallase para algunos caracteres como `@`. Una solución para poder utilizar el guión (como guión) dentro de una clase `[]`, es dejarlo en último lugar `[XYZ-]`. O puedes escaparlo con `\-`

Así pues debería funcionar.

```js
var texto='asdas@asdasd';
var patron=/^[A-ZÑÁËÍÓÚÜa-zñáéíóúü0-9;._*$%"&!()¿?{}\/-]+$/;
if ( !patron.test(texto) )
{
  console.log('Caracter no valido');
}
```

Comment: Otra opción sería escapar el guion con \ para que no lo considere como un rango.

Comment: @Alejandro Cierto, lo añado también a la respuesta